# how to use pass between 3 views (pass to the Root view ) using delegate / protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i build a app that take picture &  the user can review this picture  . after that he can see this picture
in a uicollection view

-(1 view - PicEditorViewController)
the user take the picture & pass the data to the next view using

```
let previewVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewViewController") as! PreviewViewController
previewVC.delegate = self // using the delegate
```

-(2 view  - PreviewViewController)
the user review the picture & press a button to pass date to next view (root View) using

```
    self.delegate?.previewVC1(preview: true, img : img.image)
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

in the same view  i initializ a protocol

```
protocol PreviewViewControllerDelegate  
{
    func previewVC1(preview : Bool , img : img.image)
    
}
```

- (3 view SavePicsViewController)  the Root view

the user see the picture in  uicollection view

```
extension SavePicsViewController : PreviewViewControllerDelegate
{
    func previewVC1(preview: Bool, img : img.image)
    {
         savedPic.appen(img) // the array fill the collection 
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
}
}
```

but the problem i cant call previewVC1 functon in the extension

& savedPic IS 0

how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The SavePicsViewController needs to have the property `weak var delegate: PreviewViewControllerDelegate` and needs to have it set when you instantiate it.